# Django How to allow apache to create directories?

Tags: django, apache

I am making a django application that makes user of django's ImageField to upload a file to a specific folder. I am using this field for storing the user's profile pictures. But the problem is the path that I give to `upload_to` is dynamic and depends on user and will create directories if needed. i.e if the path is `user/1/profile-pic/large/pic.jpg`, it will create the directores, `user/`, `user/1/` so on, if the are not already there. It worked fine in development. But now when I have put my website on a VM and serving it using apache. Django raises the `permission denied` error. As I have to make directories dynamically so I can't make them ahead of everything and change their permissions. So I was wondering if there is any of way of acoomplishing it.

Comment: How do you deploy the app under apache?

Comment: I am using mod_wsgi with apache. If that what you are asking?

Comment: Different deployment methods mean different assumptions about uid of the django process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `chown` you `media` directory to the user which runs you django app.

Comment: My django app is run by www-data user. After I chown it to www-data. Will it affect any other operations or any thing else? Should I change the owner or the group?

Comment: It will aftect you if you run `manage.py` command from shell and will try to write/change/delete media files from it.  In this case you should run `manage.py` from `www-data` account.

Comment: I usually deploy django app from the same user as my shell account and don't have such problems.

Comment: The error now propagates to the child directory. But the problem is the child directory is created dynamically. At the start the media directory is empty. So I can't `chown` the child directories.

Comment: Child directory created by who?  Your django app running with apache?  Who is the owner of this child directory? `www-data`?

Comment: I have an empty `media` directory the owner of which is `www-data`. But then depending on my user, child directories will be created(i.e `user/<uid>/pic/`) on run time by django(`www-data` user).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69019/discussion-between-darwesh-and-catavaran).